# cv2.imshow() window blank when used in python thread? I'm not sure how to fix this

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

I am running an IDS usb camera on a raspberry pi 3b+. I have programmed a pyqt5 GUI which has three buttons. One initialises the camera and sets up the capture. The second starts this while loop:

'''

```
def get_frame(self):
    
    capture = True
    
    while capture == True:
    
        # In order to display the image in an OpenCV window we need to...
        # ...extract the data of our image memory
        array = ueye.get_data(self.pcImageMemory, self.width, self.height, self.nBitsPerPixel, self.pitch, copy=False)
    
        # bytes_per_pixel = int(nBitsPerPixel / 8)
    
        # ...reshape it in an numpy array...
        self.frame_raw = np.reshape(array,(self.height.value, self.width.value, self.bytes_per_pixel))

        # ...resize the image by a half
        frame2 = cv2.resize(self.frame_raw,(0,0),fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
        
        #...and finally display it
        cv2.imshow("SimpleLive_Python_uEye_OpenCV", frame2)

        option = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if option == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

'''

The opencv window opens fine and displays the camera frames no problem. However, when it is open it blocks my pyqt5 GUI, meaning I can't click on the third button which saves the current camera frame from the while loop. On my windows laptop, however, my pyqt5 GUI doesn't become blocked and I can save the current frame no problem.

I have tried running the while loop in a python thread using Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=()).start(). This brings up the opencv window and doesn't block the pyqt5 GUI. However, the opencv window is just blank and doesn't show the frames. I've read that cv2.imshow() doesn't work in threads but I'm not sure how to get around this?

I would like in future to be able to run multiple cameras simultaneously and have multiple openv windows open showing the live streams.